# meteor.js: Accounts.createUser strange behavior

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to create a authorization system that is different from {{loginButtons}}
basically differs interface.

Authorization works fine through Google, Github and Facebook, but I can not just register a user by e-mail and password.

Based on this [this](http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor) tutorial, I created function:

```
Template.signup.events "submit #signup": (e, t) ->
 e.preventDefault()
 email = t.find('input[name="email"]').value
 password = t.find('input[name="password"]').value

 console.log(email)
 console.log(password)

 Accounts.createUser
   email: email
   password: password
 , (err) ->
   if err
     console.log(err)

   else
     console.log("Success!!!")

 false
```

But in

> meteor mongo

I see this:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.users.find().pretty();
{ "_id" : "hS9QkjTAN38zqfCit" }
```

And it's all!!

And where everything else? Why create only _id?!

I will be very grateful for any help (-:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! My mistake: I didn't return user object in

> Accounts.onCreateUser

when services are not defined....